# How to create reusable viewgroups in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewgroup

I often use the same LinearLayout with the same properties.
For instance:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ... other views & viewgroups here ....
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to define **an XML layout** component, let's call it *FullScreenVerticalLinearLayout*, which i would use like this:

```
<FullScreenVerticalLinearLayout>
        ... other views & viewgroups here ....
</FullScreenVerticalLinearLayout>
```

`<include>` or `<merge>` tags seem to be perfect for view's reusability and aggregation, but not for viewgroup. Any clue on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via styles. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
For example add this to styles.xml:

```
<style name="LayoutStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

And set this style:

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/LayoutStyle">
    ... other views & viewgroups here ....
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Although we are not defining a new tag, but grouping properties, this adds the readability i was looking for.